# Trying to convert .onnx model to .pb model using onnx-tf library

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert ***.onnx*** model to ***.pb*** format by using ****onnx-tf**** package, however, after invoking *onnx_tf.backend.prepare* function, the python kernel crashes. I am using the code below:

```
import onnx

from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
import tensorflow
onnx_model = onnx.load(<path-to-model>)  # load onnx model
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # <------ That's where python crashes
tf_rep.export_graph(<output-path>)  # export the model
```

I have double-checked package version dependencies, as wrong dependencies caused different errors while loading the *.onnx* model, and those are as follows:

```
onnx==1.7.0
onnx-tf==1.6.0
tensorflow==2.2.0
tensorflow-addons==0.10.0
torch==1.6.0+cu101
```

However, the dependencies seem to be correct, according to Github pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were large changes between ONNX 1.6 and 1.7 that caused many dependency issues.  Try with Onnx 1.6, which may be the source of your issue.  Where did you find 1.7 mentioned as the required version?

Additionally, you mention the Python kernel crashing?  Are you running in a Jupyter notebook?

I've found this package to be a lot more unstable in Juypter notebook, and not print out all of the relevant errors.  If you could test your system in a standalone Python script you may get more information.

Comment: Great!  Could you confirm for future readers, was it Onnx 1.6 that solved the issue, or running in a standalone script?

Comment: Downgrading from 1.7 to 1.6 solved the issue! Indeed I was running it in Jupyter Notebook previously, however, the same crash happened while running it from the Python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Importing `onnx` and `onnx-tf` related libraries before `tf` and `pytorch` should help. The problem is probably caused by a version clash since both `onnx` and `onnx-tf` use `tf`.

Comment: As you can see from my code, the import order is as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Can you install onnx-tf of this commit 7d8fa7d88fab469253d75e5e11cf9cdcb90104c4

Between order of imports and this commit the issue was solved for me